Prove that it is possible to make 0 out of 11 distinct natural numbers less than 191
I am practising for a maths competition and am stuck on this question.
Define $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$ and let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ containing $11$ distinct natural numbers strictly less than $191$. Show that it is possible to obtain the number $0$ just from addition and subtraction of elements of $X$.
I have attempted a number of approaches, from creating a group from the elements of $X$ as integers with addition, but this is not generally closed under addition (or rather showing it is is the same question as what is being asked) to generalising to a subset of $a$ elements strictly less than $b$ and finding a condition on $a$ and $b$ such that it is possible to arrive at $0$ ($11$ and $191$ seem suspiciously specific to me). Nothing I have tried has yielded any results.

Are you required to use all of the elements of $X$?

The question doesn't explicitly say, so I guess this is quite ambiguous, but I have been presuming in my attempts that yes you do.

To start:  I suggest trying simpler problems. How big a collection can you find that fails this test?

Note:  I would have assumed that you aren't required to use all of them.  After all, if all but $1$ of them is even, then no combination of them (sticking to adds and subtracts) could possibly be even.

That's a good point, thank you

As a hint:  $191+190+189+\cdots +181=2046<2048=2^{11}$.

I see how this may be useful, but I'm struggling to properly understand why it makes it possible to obtain $0$. Could you give a little more insight into what the first step may be to solve this please?

@lulu I also am struggling to understand the point of your comment.

I have just posted a solution which elaborates on the hints.

Thinking about it, I guess the trick is to prove the opposite: "Are there 11 distinct natural numbers less that 191 so that you cannot get a zero by adding or subtracting them?"

Does the empty sum count?

@user3840170 Wouldn't that just make the problem trivial? I think you ought to at least take one element.

@ReinstateMonica3167040 Indeed it would, which is why I think it ought to be explicitly excluded in the formulation of the problem.

Start with the remark:  Any combination of sums and subtractions between elements of a set $S\subset \mathbb N$ can be written as the difference of two sums.  Thus, $$s_1-s_2-s_3+s_7+s_9+s_{10}-s_{11}=(s_1+s_7+s_9+s_{10})-(s_2+s_3+s_{11})$$ for example.  So, from the start, we are looking for two disjoint subsets of $S$ with the same sum.
Now, fix a subset $S\subset \{1, \cdots, 191\}$ with $|S|=11$.  We seek to prove that $S$ must have two non-empty disjoint subsets with the same sum.
The smallest possible sum a non-empty subset of $\{1, \cdots, 191\}$ might have is $1$.
The largest, given that the subset has $11$ or fewer elements,  is $191+190+\cdots +181=2046$.
Hence, in principle,  there are only $2046$ possible sums one can make from subsets of $S$.  But $S$ has $2^{11}=2048$ subsets of which all but $1$ is non-empty.  Since $2047>2046$ there must be two distinct non-empty subsets of $S$ with the same sum.  Removing any shared elements doesn't change the fact that the sums are the same, so we must have two disjoint subsets $S_1, S_2$ with the same sum.  Now, subtracting the sum of the elements in $S_2$ from the sum of the elements in $S_1$ yields $0$. And we are done.
Might add:  $\{1, 2, 4, 8,16,32,64, 128\}$ has $8$ elements and no two disjoint subsets have the same sum.  It's clear that you can't add a $9^{th}$ to that particular set unless you go up to $256$.  This may suggest that you can rule out sets with size $9$ or $10$ as well, but I have not thought that through. Conway-Guy sets might do better, I am not sure. I note that the general question, replacing $191$ with a general cap $N$, is open.
Update:  The Conway Guy set $\{77,117,137, 148,154,157,159,160,161\}$  has $9$ elements and has distinct subset sums (this is not obvious but, if I have not introduced any errors, it should follow from the work of Conway and Guy).  Their set with $10$ elements has maximal element $301$, though, so I think $10$ is impossible.  As I say, however, the general problem remains open.  It is not known that the Conway Guy set is optimal in general.  See A005318 for more details.

This almost certainly should have been closed as a duplicate. Lots of versions of it exist already. $\quad$ See this for a slightly harder version.

@CalvinLin  Yes, you are probably right.  I thought my hint in the comments would suffice...when it didn't, I just wrote it out.  Question, though:  do you see how to rule out sets of size $10$ here?  I think I used the Conway-Guy theory correctly, but of course we don't know that it always finds the biggest set.  For small caps, like $191$, surely there is a simpler approach?

Nothing comes to mind. The 191 is too large.

191 choose 10 is merely 14,012,323,932,439,833.  At 5 billion per second that is only 32 days...  but you can't check in a single instruction.  3^10 is a mere 60,000 - so a few thousand computers running for a month could check every possibility of 10 element subsets under 191 and solve this using a massively naive algorithm?

@Yakk  Sure, but...well, it's so easy to rule out $11$.  And the bounds used to rule out $11$ are very crude.  They can be tightened considerably, though not far enough to rule out $10$ as far as I can see.
